# audio player for joomla

Tags: joomla, audio-player

i am making a website with joomla and one thing i am trying to do is on one of the page i want to make an audio player for a list of audio files i'll be adding every week. everybody would be able to listen to or download and comment on the audio just like soundcloud.com
i have already tried some plugins but all they do is get list of mp3 file in one directory and play them. problem with that is people wont be able to comment on the tracks.
my question, is there a plugin/module out there that do something similar and is non-commercial or free or do i have to program it my self.
thanks

Comment: For this you will need a component and there aren'y any free ones on the JED website. You're either going to have to develop your own or invest one one of the pre-made extensions.

Comment: @Lodder that's not true. There's actually a few...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [K2](http://www.getk2.org)  using the [AllVideos Plugin](http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free-premium/allvideos).
Both are free and open source and K2 has built in comments.

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thank you Adam!!!! you saved me a lot of time. this is exactly what i needed + more...